# How to write a query to find a documents which is created after " Aug 1 ,2020,3:58:56 PM"

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

How to write a query to find documents which are created after "Aug 1 ,2020,3:58:56 PM".
I need to find documents from Cloudant which is greater than particular date. At Cloudant date is stored as "May 18, 2020, 3:58:56 PM".

when I try to query like below:

```json
{
    "selector": {
        "$and": [
            {
                "project.projectId": {
                    "$eq": 34567
                }
            },
            {
                "createdDate": {
                    "$gte": "Aug  1 ,2020,3:58:56 PM"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am getting 2019 data also. The proper search is not working.

What is the right way to filter date?

Answer (score 2):

The date in your documents is a non-comparable string. You're asking Cloudant Query to do a lexicographic string comparison. For that to work, your date strings need to be in a comparable format, like "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS". However, the better solution is to use a numeric datetime.

If you don't want to modify your documents to use a different format, create a map-reduce view that first parses the date string, and then emits a vector-valued key:

```
d = Date.parse(doc.createdDate);
emit([doc.projectId, d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth()+1, d.getDate()], [...]);
```

and you can do elegant range queries from this view.

Some useful examples and other date-related tricks here: https://blog.cloudant.com/2018/08/24/Time-sortable-document-ids.html